# Проверить, возможно ли достроить стену с данным набором кирпичей

Tags: javascript, php, java, jquery, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите написать код на js для следуещого задания.

Условие:
В программу надо ввести размер прямоугольной матрицы(1 - кирпич, 0 - пустота). Далее вести количество видов блоков и характеристики самих блоков(длина,высота и количество).
Вывести "да", если возможно построить, или "нет", если невозможно.
Блоки могут стоять как вертикально так и горизонтально.

Пример ввода и вывода данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

После выполнения очевидных проверок (например, что площадь всех входных блоков больше или равна площади свободных мест на стене), а также выбросив блоки, у которых одно из измерений превосходит соответствующее измерение матрицы, можно приступать к строительству.

Алгоритм будет из семейства рекурсивных переборов с возвратами, и будет оперировать такой сущностью как *поколение решений*

**Первое поколение решений**

Выберем из коллекции наших блоков по одному представителю каждого типа. Возьмем блок первого типа и найдем ему подходящее место в матрице, перебирая ее элементы слева направо, сверху-вниз. Если место нашлось, мы получили новую матрицу и новую коллекцию блоков (за исключением использованного) , и можем рекурсивно зациклиться. В противном случае, отбрасываем этот блок и пробуем поставить на стенку следующий блок.

**Очередное поколение решений**

Если из рекурсии мы вышли ни с чем, мы можем пытаться поставить блок из коллекции не на первое, а на второе попавшееся для него место. А потом на третье, и так далее.

Условием выхода из рекурсии будет либо исчерпание коллекции блоков (и тогда у нас провал, стена не построилась), либо заполнение матрицы.